# C# WPF value converter receiving entire collection instead of single item as value parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have a C# WPF 4.51 application.  On one of my XAML forms I have a list box that has its **ItemsSource** property bound to a property in my main *ViewModel* that is of type *Collection*.  When the Collection was of type **string**, everything worked fine and I saw the collection of strings in the list box.

But then I changed the type in the Collection to a class named **ObservableStringExt**.  The class has two fields: **StrItem** that contains the string I want displayed in the list box, and **IsSelected**, a supporting field.  I then created a value converter to extract the StrItem field and return it.

However, when I look at the targetType passed to the Convert() method of the value converter I see a type of **IEnumerable**.  Given that the **Count** property in that parameter matches the number of list items expected, it looks like the Convert() method is **receiving a reference to the entire Collection** *instead* of **ObservableStringExt**, the type of each item in the Collection.  This of course is a problem.  What is causing this?  I have done this sort of thing many times in Windows Phone and WinRT (windows store apps) many times without trouble.

Here is the code for the value converter:

```
public class ObservableStringExtToStrItem : IValueConverter
{
    // The targetType of the value received is of type IEnumerable, not ObservableStringExt.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ObservableStringExt)
            return (value as ObservableStringExt).StrItem;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Below is the XAML code for the list box.  Note **Commands_FrequentyUsed** is a property of type **ObservableCollectionWithFile** found in the main view model, which is the *data context* for the entire form:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listFrequentlyUsedCommands"
             Width="278"
             Height="236"
             Margin="30,103,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Commands_FrequentyUsed.Collection,
                                   Converter={StaticResource ObservableStringExtToStrItem}}" />
```

Here is the code for the class that contains the Collection that the list box binds to and the class the Collection contains:

```
public class ObservableStringExt
{
    public string StrItem { get; set;}
    public bool IsSelected{ get; set; }
}

public class ObservableCollectionWithFile : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public const string CollectionPropertyName = "Collection";
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableStringExt> _observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<ObservableStringExt>();

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableStringExt> Collection
    {
        get { return _observableCollection; }
        private set { SetField(ref _observableCollection, value); }
    }
} // public class ObservableCollectionWithFile
```

Comment: what about the actual type of `value`, have you checked it?

Comment: Your code doesn't add up. Yes Collection in ObservableCollectionWithFile is ObservableCollection, alright .... but What's the return of Commands_FrequentyUsed.Collection could be different

Comment: I put the code in the test project without the Commands_FrequentlyUserd part. I can get the value in the converter as ObservableCollection which looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @csmh99 It's supposed to be of type ObservableStringExt, a single item in the collection, not an entire collection.

Comment: Do you mean `Commands_FrequentyUsed.Collection` is just a single item? It's obviously a collection of items. And that's what will be passed in the convert (as the raw bound value).

Comment: @KingKing - It's a collection but my experience is that the data binding code recognizes that and calls the value converter for each item.  If you look at the samples on line for data binding that's how it normally works and that's how it has worked for me with WinPhone and WinRT.

Comment: From my experience that is not how it works in desktop wpf. Maybe it behaves differently in different platforms. Also if the purpose is showing `StrItem`, you don't need any converter. Just change the `ItemTemplate` of your ListBox so that each one is bound to `StrItem`. That is how it should be done.

Comment: it can be simpler by setting `DisplayMemberPath` to `StrItem`.

Comment: I'm saying that Commands_FrequentyUsed.Collection seems to be rerturning an IEnumerable instead of ObservableCollection. Please double check your code. @RobertOschler: ItemsSource is supposed to bind to a collection instead of single item.

Comment: @cscmh99 Commands_FrequentyUsed.Collection is returning an object of type ObservableCollection<ObservableStringExt>.  You can see the Collection property in the last code block in my post.  That is the property I data bind to, which appears in the data binding helper dialog as a child property of Commands_FrequentyUsed, since it is of type ObservableCollectionWithFile.

Comment: @KingKing Just tried that no luck.  Probably related to the original problem I'm having, something weird in the data context path/tree.  Overriding ToString() on ObserverStringExt to return StrItem, and then removing the converter did work.  I see the correct strings now.  I still need to get this problem solved though to be able to do some of the other value conversions I'll need to do later.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Not sure how it should normally work, but changing the converter to also convert list of items helped (I found this easier than creating a separate converter for List)

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var list = value as IEnumerable<ObservableStringExt>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        return list.Select(x => Convert(x, typeof(string), null, culture));
    }
    if (value is ObservableStringExt)
        return (value as ObservableStringExt).StrItem;
}
```